# Apache Solr suggester and Umlauts

Tags: apache, solr

I'm using Solr 7.7.0 and it's basically working well so far.

It's just that the suggester doesn't return any Umlauts (ö,ä,ü,é...).

So for example when I search for «Olivenöl», the suggester returns «Oliven l».

The search works perfectly, so if I ignore the suggester and just search for «Olivenöl», the correct results are returned.

Any ideas?

Comment: What's the definition of the field you're building the suggestions from? Are you looking at the suggestion in the raw response from Solr, or after going through your controller/etc.?

Comment: OMG, thanks for pointing that out. I just looked at the definition and I have patternReplaceCharFilteFactory in there... feel a little stupid right now... ;) Thanks!